# What is the use of the floodlight and the scoreboard?

Tags: top-eleven-be-a-football-manager

In the Facebook game,  [Top Eleven - Be a Football Manager](https://www.facebook.com/topeleven), there are a lot of buildings which are really useful and which have a description that says things like "Your players have less risk of getting injured while playing on that field", for example.

But the scoreboard, for example, just goes with "It's a key factor for exciting soccer mood", for the floodlight: "It's important for late night games and big events". I can't figure out if I really need to build those things. It seems that I have to build them if I want to upgrade other buildings but I still don't know if I can take any advantage of those things.

Comment: I've edited in the game tag for the question, and linked to what I think is the webpage of the game in your question. Let me know if it's correct or not.

Comment: Yea that's it. I don't have enough repu for making a top-eleven tag so I put it in the title. I just took a look at the website you linked in the revision description, I will never greet again! :D Thanks for the teaching :)